# Regenerate lost identity value

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

Is there a way to recreate the identity value of a SQL Server table if the statements failed inside a transaction block?

Please go through the code below:

```
DECLARE @IdentityTable AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Description VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @IdentityTable (Description) 
VALUES('Test1')

BEGIN TRY 
BEGIN TRANSACTION IdentityTest
    INSERT INTO @IdentityTable (Description) 
    VALUES('Test2')

    INSERT INTO @IdentityTable (Description) 
    VALUES(1/0)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION IdentityTest
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION IdentityTest
END CATCH

INSERT INTO @IdentityTable (Description) 
VALUES('Test4')

SELECT * FROM @IdentityTable
```

[image: Result]

Identity No 3 is lost due to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. Is it possible to regain it?

Comment: Why do you think you need this value?  Let SQL Server worry about maintaining the identity column; that's what it's for.  If you need a sequence across your table, just use things like `ROW_NUMBER` or maybe one of the `RANK` functions.

Comment: Do you want to reset existing ids and set 3 instead of 4 or adding a new row with id=3 ?

Comment: It is possible. However, I strongly urge you not to rely on this and use the windowing functions already mentioned. If you really, really do want to use it then reply to this and I'll post some code.

Comment: I would like to note that this idea of wanting a "gapless sequence" is quite a common one (try searching this site or the web for that term). It's very rare to actually need it (rather than just thinking it would look nicer) but just occasionally there are valid use cases, like generating numbers for invoices or other legal documents. However, "recovering a rolled back value" is not a viable approach to this problem (that's just not what IDENTITY sequences are for), so the only valid answer to this question is "you can't".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use the `IDENTITY` property to generate consecutive numbers, and maintain it; that isn't what `IDENTITY` is for. It's designed to provide an incrementing value based on the current seed (on it's own (without a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint or `UNIQUE INDEX`), it doesn't even guarantee uniqueness as the seed could be changed (*thanks HoneyBadger for reminding me so early in the morning*)).

If an `INSERT` fails, the value of the `IDENTITY` will still be incremented. Also, if you were to `DELETE` a row from a table, that would not cause every "latter" row to have their ID's updated accordingly; thus you would also have a gap then.

The only guaranteed way of ensuring you get an incrementing value is by using a function like `ROW_NUMBER` at *run time*. For example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS cID,
       Description
FROM YourTable;
```

The [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) section of the documentation specifically states that consecutive values are *not* guarenteed:

> Identity columns can be used for generating key values. The identity
>   property on a column guarantees the following:
>
> ...
>
> **Consecutive values within a transaction** – A transaction inserting
>   multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>   because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>   must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>   on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
>
> **Consecutive values after server restart or other failures** – SQL Server
>   might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the
>   assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>   restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If
>   gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own
>   mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the
>   NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never
>   committed.
>
> **Reuse of values** – For a given identity property with specific
>   seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a
>   particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled
>   back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be
>   generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity
>   values are generated.

Comment: "It's designed to ensure that every row has a unique value", yet in the link you provide it is stated that "The identity property on a column does not guarantee ... Uniqueness of the value". A bit nit picky on a good answer, I know.

Comment: @HoneyBadger very true, I should reword that; I'm just far too used to having the `IDENTITY` and a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX` being applied to the same column that this early in the morning it  slipped my mind.

Comment: @HoneyBadger reworded. I wouldn't say it's nit picky at all; the statement was untrue. It's important for the OP, and others to be given the correct information so I'm always grateful for constructive feedback on any answers I post. Thanks.

Comment: Very true. Its an early morning for me too. I'm always a bit more hesitant when my brain isn't fully restored yet.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is *not* the only way to guarantee a sequential number.  The alternative is a total lock on the table for all update/insert/delete operations.  That is very expensive and generally not desirable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff although true, that wouldn't help the OP with failed inserts; the seed would still be incremented if the transaction was rolled back. This would mean that error handling to reseed to the `IDENTITY` value would also be needed. You'd also need triggers to resolve any `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements to ensure the numbering is still "correct". Yes, I *suppose* you could go through a lot of hoops to achieve this at the DML point, but, like you suggested, the behaviour is often far less than desirable.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I wasn't referring to an `identity` column -- just a full table lock, a trigger that reads the entire table to get the maximum value, and then `+ 1`.  Not recommended, but possible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ahh, sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, that would certainly work as well (wouldn't solve any deletes mind, without the use of a trigger, but would reuse the "top" value), but far from ideal; especially if the table is often used.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I like to explain what is needed for a gapless identity, to create appreciation for what `identity` actually does.  It is quite useful and has way less overhead.